# Test if all N variables are different

Tags: python, logical-operators, boolean-logic, idioms

I want to make a condition where all selected variables are not equal.
My solution so far is to compare every pair which doesn't scale well:

```
if A!=B and A!=C and B!=C:
```

I want to do the same check for multiple variables, say five or more, and it gets quite confusing with that many. What can I do to make it simpler?

Comment: What are you actually doing that requires you to check that many conditions?  This has a bit of a code smell to it.

Comment: I agree with @Makoto. What's requiring you to do this? This sounds like an xy problem.

Comment: It is a program which checks votes of 5 candidates basically it counts a list which has preference votes from 1 to 5, the one with the highest amount of '1' votes is chosen as the winner but if one or more have the same amount of '1' votes it then chooses the winner based on '2' preference votes and if they're the same then it does '3' votes and so on. It's a little long-winded but that was the task set and I have it all sorted apart from this part of the code.

Comment: can you add an example as there is probably an easier way to do what you want

Comment: How is this candidate information stored?  Is it an explicit class; that is, are the tallies of votes an explicitly represented class?  It may be better for you to post that code as what you're asking for and what you're actually getting are a bit different...

Comment: @Ben.Sw, Makato is correct, what A,B and C actually are is pretty important as to what is going to work, your description also does not seem to match up to what you are asking at all

Comment: Instead of individually-named variables `A,B,C,...`, you might as well keep them in either a list `votes[1:5]`. Then simply do `len(set(votes)) == len(votes)`. Or else a hash if you want to access elements by name, e.g. `votes['Alice'], votes['Bob']...`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a set and check whether the number of elements in the set is the same as the number of variables in the list that you passed into it:

```
>>> variables = [a, b, c, d, e]
>>> if len(set(variables)) == len(variables):
...     print("All variables are different")
```

A set doesn't have duplicate elements so if you create a set and it has the same number of elements as the number of elements in the original list then you know all elements are different from each other.

Comment: presuming the objects are hashable

Comment: This also first creates the entire set an thus cannot fail early. The for loop could already abort when the first two items are different. The average runtime thus depends on how often differences are expected in the data.

Comment: While this may be a good answer, I feel that this hasn't really addressed the  actual problem.  The asker should come back (hopefully) to clarify, but this sort of answer would only serve to confuse one further than to help with anything.

Answer (score 6):

If you can hash your variables (and, uh, your variables have a meaningful `__hash__`), use a set.

```
def check_all_unique(li):
    unique = set()
    for i in li:
        if i in unique: return False #hey I've seen you before...
        unique.add(i)
    return True #nope, saw no one twice.
```

O(n) worst case. (And yes, I'm aware that you can also `len(li) == len(set(li))`, but this variant returns early if a match is found)

If you can't hash your values (for whatever reason) but can meaningfully compare them:

```
def check_all_unique(li):
    li.sort()
    for i in range(1,len(li)):
       if li[i-1] == li[i]: return False
    return True
```

O(nlogn), because sorting. Basically, sort everything, and compare pairwise. If two things are equal, they should have sorted next to each other. (If, for some reason, your `__cmp__` doesn't sort things that are the same next to each other, 1. wut and 2. please continue to the next method.)

And if `ne` is the only operator you have....

```
import operator
import itertools
li = #a list containing all the variables I must check
if all(operator.ne(*i) for i in itertools.combinations(li,2)):
   #do something
```

I'm basically using `itertools.combinations` to pair off all the variables, and then using `operator.ne` to check for not-equalness. This has a worst-case time complexity of O(n^2), although it should still short-circuit (because generators, and `all` is lazy). If you are absolutely sure that `ne` and `eq` are opposites, you can use `operator.eq` and `any` instead.

Addendum: [Vincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846140/vincent) wrote a *much* more readable version of the `itertools` variant that looks like

```
import itertools
lst = #a list containing all the variables I must check
if all(a!=b for a,b in itertools.combinations(lst,2)):
   #do something
```

Addendum 2: Uh, for sufficiently large datasets, the sorting variant should possibly use `heapq`. Still would be O(nlogn) worst case, but O(n) best case. It'd be something like

```
import heapq
def check_all_unique(li):
    heapq.heapify(li) #O(n), compared to sorting's O(nlogn)
    prev = heapq.heappop(li)
    for _ in range(len(li)): #O(n)
       current = heapq.heappop(li) #O(logn)
       if current == prev: return False
       prev = current
    return True
```

Comment: I don't think it is that ugly, especially if you get rid of `operator.ne`. Something like `all(a != b for a, b in combinations(lst, 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the values into a container type. Then just loop trough the container, comparing each value. It would take about O(n^2).

pseudo code:

```
a[0] = A; a[1] = B ... a[n];

for i = 0 to n do
  for j = i + 1 to n do
      if a[i] == a[j]
         condition failed
```

Comment: Better yet, why not just start with an array in first place. This is ideal for variables that are closely related, such as is your case when you need to compare a list of variables to each other.

Comment: But creating `set(variables)` is only O(n), and a very fast O(n) at that.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't that into account. Yes one probably could optimize.

Comment: Nested for-loops (esp. over the same range) is a code smell that you're doing something inefficiently...

Comment: Well, definitely for that in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate a list and check that all values are the first occurrence of that value in the list:

```
a = [5, 15, 20, 65, 48]
if all(a.index(v) == i for i, v in enumerate(a)):
    print "all elements are unique"
```

This allows for short-circuiting once the first duplicate is detected due to the behaviour of Python's all() function.

Or equivalently, enumerate a list and check if there are any values which are not the first occurrence of that value in the list:

```
a = [5, 15, 20, 65, 48]
if not any(a.index(v) != i for i, v in enumerate(a)):
    print "all elements are unique"
```