# How can I check if 3 random strings are not equal in a single if statement?

Tags: python

How can I check if 3 random strings are not equal **in a single** `if` statement?  I know I could do it with multiple `if` statements but that would make my code look very busy. . .

For example:

```
bookie1 = "a"
bookie2 = "b"
bookie3 = "c"

if bookie1 != bookie2 != bookie1:
    print(True)
```

This returns true even though `bookie1` at the beginning of the `if` statement is equal to `bookie1` at the end of the `if` statement.

EDIT:
I know I could use `and` statements but let's say I had like 10+ variables this can get messy really fast.  Is there another, more pythonic way of doing it?

Found answers I was looking for on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505075/test-if-all-n-variables-are-different)

Comment: actually that's working, just use as `if bookie1 == bookie2 == bookie3:` then your code thats all.

Comment: @AliAref no, that would translate into `if (bookie1 == bookie2) == bookie3:` which would in turn become `if TRUE/FALSE == bookie3` which is not what we're looking for

Comment: @Adalcar I just test it again it works(becomes True if all tree values are same and false when if one of tree values is different or more).

Comment: @AliAref Ah my bad: Learned something today. 
However, what works for equality doesn't work for inequality, because every operation is independent: if he wants to test whether EACH of his values is unique, he has to add a third test `bookie1 != bookie2 != bookie3 != bookie1` and it gets more complicated with each additional variable

Answer (score 0):

You could use"or" , "and" in your code.

Comment: Let's say I had like 7 different variables this can start to look super messy with a ton of `and` statements.

Comment: Well you can write functions for that

Answer (score 0):

Using and operator:

```
if bookie1 != bookie2 and bookie1 != bookie3 and bookie2 != bookie3:
    print(True)
```